# It is possible to print but not download images?

Tags: html, browser, user-permissions, save-as

I have been investigating for days if it is possible to allow a user to print an image on any printer that they have connected but not allow them to save the image on their computer, that is, disable the possibility of saving as pdf of the printout.

I clarify that it is not important if you take captures and other metedos that may exist, I would only be interested in disabling the option when clicking print.

[Image of the detail that I want to avoid being seen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zkbm7.png)

Thank you in advance for the time to respond, greetings.

Comment: The dialog that is in the screenshot you have linked is controlled by the operating system, therefore I do not think what you are attempting to do is possible.

Answer (score -2):

You can use a link to a file that you would like to print, the file will not download:

```html
<a href="https://oh-aha.com" onclick="window.print();return false;">Print the file</a>
```

Currently it is not possible to disable the option of saving as PDF.